# Matriz no Forms

Tags: java, swing, matriz, netbeans

Eu estou com dificuldades para criar uma matriz dentro de um `JPanel` no NetBeans, eu tentei personalizar o código colocando dentro da personalização do NetBeans o código:

> ```
>            jPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(15,15));
>            JLabel[][] grid = new JLabel[15][15]; 
>            for(int y=0; y<15; y++){
>                    for(int x=0; x<15; x++){
>                           grid[x][y]=new JLabel("("+x+","+y+")");    
>                           jPanel1.add(grid[x][y]);
>                    }
>            }
> ```

Só que não mostra nada, eu queria *printar* uma matriz na interface pois preciso disso no desenvolvimento de um joguinho.

Comment: Talvez devesse colocar mais do seu código para entender pq que não _printa_ nada, aparentemente esse seu código tb era para funcionar, eu sugeri o MigLayout pois já havia feito um código semelhante com ele antes.

Answer (score 4):

Como você disse que o programa não *printa* **nada** acredito que não é um problema com a escolha do Layout Manager, deve estar faltando adicionar o seu JPanel ao seu JFrame, assim:

```
setContentPane(jPanel1);
```

Entretanto, fica minha sugestão de sempre que estiver na dúvida de qual LayoutManager utilizar, vá de MigLayout, por ser mais moderno que os demais, mais flexível e que gera menos código, facilitando caso você precise mexer nas linhas de códigos ao invés de apenas arrastar os componentes. Fonte: [MigLayout - Java Layout Manager](http://www.miglayout.com/)

Usando MigLayout ao invés do GridLayout seu código ficaria assim:

```
jPanel1 = new JPanel();
jPanel1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
setContentPane(jPanel1);
jPanel1.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[][]", "[]"));
JLabel[][] grid = new JLabel[15][15];
for(int y=0; y<15; y++){
    for(int x=0; x<15; x++){
        grid[x][y]=new JLabel("("+x+","+y+")");    
        jPanel1.add(grid[x][y], "cell " + x  + " " + y);
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse MigLayout é uma biblioteca, ou um programa de Design de Interface Grafica?

Comment: @JoãoCarlos Ele é uma biblioteca, mas isso na verdade é transparente para o desenvolvedor, pois você usa ele assim como qualquer outro Layout Manager. Veja no meu código que estou usando `new MigLayout` ao invés de `new GridLayout`. Esse código funciona para você? Caso negativo, me informe a versão do Java que está utilizando.